# Pictures & Tags - Database Design Question

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 3 tables which allows me to get all tags of some picture, or all pictures with a specific tag.

I would like also to know the number of times each tag exist. How could I get this info using MySQL ?

Is it worth to add a "Count" column to the `Tags` table to hold this info ?

### Files Table

```
File ID    File Name    ...
-------    ---------
   1         a.jpg      ...
   2         b.png      ...
   3         c.jpg      ...
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
```

### Tags Table

```
Tag Name    Tag Creator     ...
--------    -----------  
 David        david         ...
 2010         julia         ...
   .            .
   .            .
   .            .
```

### FilesTags Table

```
File ID    Tag Name
-------    --------  
   1        2010
   1        April
   1        David
   2        2010
   2        Julia
   3        Friends
   .          .
   .          .
   .          .
```

Comment: You'll likely run into issues, using a natural key for the TAGS primary key.  String based keys are slower because in MySQL VARCHAR(4) is the same space as INT - over that, and you're using more space than an INT.  Plus, if you want to change the tagname value - you're going to have to update all the supporting references in the FilesTags table.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: That's what foreign key with cascading update is for (but not supported in Oracle).  Also, there are advantages to using a natural primary key:  you don't have to do an extra join to get the tag string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT FilesTags.Tag_name, COUNT(*) as number_of_occurences
FROM FilesTags
GROUP BY FilesTags.Tag_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

[Zaki's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378775/pictures-tags-database-design-question/3378811#3378811) answers one of your questions but not the other one.

> "Is it worth to add a "Count" column
>   to the Tags table to hold this info ?"

It really depends on what you are going to do with the counts.  Which in turn depends on the nature of your web site.

SO makes displays the counts alongside the tags; that's partly because its target audience is geeks and geeks like numbers.  But also the count is useful information when it comes to tagging a question.  Plus there's the Taxonomist's badge to consider, and the display of new tags on the Moderators' page.  In other words, there's a lot of calls on the count, so it makes sense to hold and maintain the count against each tag.

Other sites don't extract nearly as much juice out of their tags.  But, as an example, say you want to display a [tag cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud); you might want to be avoid counting all the entries in `FileTags` each time you render it.  Holding the count would then be a help.

But remember, writes can be expensive.  So have a clear idea what you are going to do with the counts before you decide to store them.  Maintaining them asynchronously, perhaps in a batched job, would be a good idea.

Comment: +1 for explaining when to have a "count" column. The bottom line is it depends.

Comment: @Zaki - the bottom line for most design decisions is "it depends* :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of times tag "ABC" occurs just do

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FilesTags Table WHERE Tag Name = "ABC";

Hope this helps.